# How can I fuzzy search a pdf file

Tags: linux, windows-10, pdf, search

I'd like to look for textual information in pdf files where words are not necessarily linked together. For example, I'd like to input "Super" and "question" and have the following sentence in the output (if it is in the pdf file):

Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

How can I achieve this? If this is not possible can I do it in txt? Preferably the solution should also show the search context (a few lines up and below) and is fast enough (through indexing?).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Was the PDF saved as Searchable Text. If so, make sure Index Properties for PDF type include Content searches (option to be enabled).

If not, you need to print, and scan with an OCR app such as Abbey Fine Reader and use the app’s search features.

Comment: Thanks! I can't really find the "Content" option in this [page](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/creating-pdf-indexes.html). Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: The "Content" option is in Index Options. Set it so that when you search for information in Searchable PDF files, you find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using free tool called [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html). It cand index multiple files and then quick search through all of them. It supports also Proximity search as you want. Here is relevant part form search manual:

*Proximity searches allow you to find words that are within a specific distance away from each other. To do a proximity search, put a tilde ('~') at the end of a phrase, followed by a distance value. — Note that this is syntactically similar to fuzzy searches. For example, to search for documents containing wikipedia and lucene within 10 words of each other, type in: "wikipedia lucene"~10*